# regex for replacing html tags with whats between them

Tags: regex

Previously webpage had all information stored in html tables, now it is stored in xml files and the tables are dynamically generated.

Now, I have to manually change html files to xml one. I'm trying to create regex which would change

```
<tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
</tr>
```

to

```
 <a>b</a>
```

(I'm editing the file in notepad++, and it supposedly supports regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find what:

```
<tr>\s*<td>(.*?)</td>\s*<td>(.*?)</td>\s*</tr>
```

Replace with:

```
<$1>$2</$1>
```

Please select regular expression mode.